# Using Asp.Net and SignalR but my server method isn't returning any data?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr

I've created an ASP.NET MVC5 app with signalR for the backend and using javascript for the front end (it's mainly for learning). Functionally, it's very simple it just allows any connected client to see a list of items and each client can add/delete an item. Any changes to the list are updated asynchronously on all clients. I've hooked up my client code to my hub which seems to be working (as confirmed by the console.log statements) but my server methods don't seem to be working i.e. when I try to add a new item using the method AddItem(), I do not get a list of updated values back.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I've added my code to GitHub to make it easier for someone to take a look: https://github.com/mildeveloper/ItemListWebApp/tree/develop

This is my javascript code:

```
(function () {
    var itemHub = $.connection.itemHub;

    var updateItemsRetrievedByClient = function (items) {
        console.log("Items obtained by client: " + items.length.toString());
        $("#item-list").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            $("#item-list").append("From client: " + items[i] + "<br/>");
        }
    };

    var updateItemsPushedFromServer = function (items) {
        console.log("Items received from server: " + items.length.toString());
        $("#item-list").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            $("#item-list").append("From server: " + items[i] + "<br/>");
        }
    };

    $("#submit").on("click",
        function () {
            var text = $("#textname").val();
            itemHub.server.addItem(text)
                .done(function() {
                    console.log("Adding item: " + text);
                })
                .fail(function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });

            itemHub.server.getItems()
                .done(function (items) {
                    updateItemsRetrievedByClient(items);
                })
                .fail(function(e) {
                    console.log(e);
                });
        });

    $.connection.hub.start()
        .done(function () {
            console.log("Connected to SignalR hub");
        })
        .fail(function (e) { console.log(e) });

    itemHub.client.itemListUpdated = updateItemsPushedFromServer;
})()
```

And this is my hub class:

```
public class ItemHub : Hub
{
    public void AddItem(string item)
    {
        ItemListController.AddItem(item);
        var items = ItemListController.GetItems();
        Clients.All.ItemListUpdated(items);
    }

    public void DeleteItem(string item)
    {
        ItemListController.DeleteItem(item);
        var items = ItemListController.GetItems();
        Clients.All.ItemListUpdated(items);
    }

    public string[] GetItems()
    {
        var items = ItemListController.GetItems();
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you could share the piece of code you want us to look at.

Comment: A lot of people (including myself) don't click on links in questions, so to @hardkoded's point, can you include the useful code?

Comment: Post what the console.log looks like after adding the item

Comment: Apologies for not posting the code directly in the post, I shall do this in future. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug in your ItemsController.cs

```
public static void AddItem(string itemName)
{
    lock (ItemNamesLock)
    {
        //if (!itemName.Contains(itemName)) original
        if (!ItemNames.Items.Contains(itemName))
        {
            ItemNames.Items.Add(itemName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the call to `getItems`, `addItem` is doing that for you.

And then, you need to register client callbacks before calling the `start` function:

```
itemHub.client.itemListUpdated = updateItemsPushedFromServer;
$.connection.hub.start();
```